# SoundCloud login problem with Selenium Chromedriver Python

Tags: python, selenium, soundcloud

I am trying to login in SoundCloud with Selenium Chromedriver Python.

But I am getting the following message while pressing the sign-in button.

**Our robots think you are a robot.**

Please check the attached image for more info.

[image]

I am using the following code in my chromedriver:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-error")
options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'path\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```

Can anyone tell me how to bypass this problem to login to SoundCloud?

Comment: What is the url you are trying to access?

Comment: https://soundcloud.com/signin

Comment: @JamesHorab, I am no sure what is goal with soundcloud but looks like you may have to use [soundcloud API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide)

Comment: Soundcloud API not allow to register a new app:(https://soundcloud.com/you/apps)
> Due to the high amount of requests recently received, we will no longer be processing API application requests at this time. We are working to re-evaluate our process to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It could help when you do the input with ActionChains and type the username and password string character by character.

Comment: I tried this approach, doesn't help. The same outcome.